# If God exists why doesn't he want to be seen?

Tags: gods

It is a question which has bothered me for a while. If we know that God exists why doesn't he want to be seen? Why is it that no human being has a true description of the God?

Comment: The short answer is that it's the Kali Yuga.  Human interactions with the gods vary based on the Yugas.  Like back when Yudhisthira was performing Yagnas, the gods would appear in person to accept his offerings.

Comment: There are plenty of people who have seen and described God to their best possible effort. Sri Ramakrishna said "I have spoken to God the way I speak to you right now". But you see, God is there right in front of us. But we have closed the 'eye' and complain that we are cannot see Him. If only we open our inner eye, we can see God, God and nothing but God. All the best.

Comment: I would say that even if God comes today in front of us, how will you believe whether He is God or not. Even in earlier God's own time, there were several people who didn't believe they were Gods and it was only later when it was certified in our books like puranas, Vedas, upnishads, etc that people start believing them. But even now there are people who don't believe in these books.

Comment: God doesn't need any certification that he is God. Its only us that need certification and therefore books are written for us. Also, God doesn't need to be physically present to solve our problems. He is within everyone, everything. He can create a mere small circumstance to solve your problem, so there's no need of him to be physically present.

Comment: God don't get seen currently to us in kaliyuga.But at time he sends you the signal that he is just around you,the only thing is that you might be able to understand the sign he sends you

Comment: If you have not seen god, how could you believe him?

Comment: If God could be seen in this life, the test of this life would be POINTLESS. The test is to see if you believe in him or not without seeing him.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Lord is all around you, but you cannot see God because you have since the instance of your birth been bombarded by your senses to perceive the world. Your senses have been bombarding you to see the outer world and not God. Your mind has been hypnotized into seeing this world alone, what is needed is to be de-hypnotized. This hypnotization is called *Adhyasa*, or superimposition. We see Reality, but it is distorted through maya. In many scriptural instances it is compared to silver in mother-of-pearl. The shell is real, but the silver on the shell is not real.

Sankara says that it is not through learning, or scriptural study, that the Lord is seen, but only through an intense hankering. Ramakrishna Paramahamsa told the story (*Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna*) of the man who asked his guru what was necessary to see God. The guru took him to a river and had him stand in it next to him. The guru then suddenly pushed the man's head under water. After a while, he let him above the water. The guru said "What did you feel?" The man replied "The intense desire for a breath of air completely consumed me." and the guru responded "When you have the same longing for God as you had for a breath of air, you will see God."

The *Mundaka Upanishad* (III. ii. 3.) says:

> This Self is not attained through study, nor through intellect, nor through much hearing. By the very fact that he (the aspirant) seeks for It [*vrnute tena* - seeks to reach by that fact of hankering], does It become attainable; of him this Self reveals Its own nature.

Swami Shivananda (disciple of Ramakrishna Paramahamsa) says (*For Seekers of God*):

> Spiritual efforts without sincere love of God are fruitless. Sincere love is what counts. The Master [Ramakrishna] used to say that when the three attachments--that of a devoted wife to her husband, of a mother for her child, and of a miser for his wealth--become one, then one realizes God. If anyone feels the same intense longing as would result if these three attachments were united, only then does he have God-vision. Sincere love brings God-realization and in that alone is genuine peace and joy.

Why is there no human description of God? Because God is beyond description. There are no words to describe God. Krishna says (Gita XI. 12.):

> If the radiance of a thousand suns were to burst forth at once in the sky, that would be like the splendor of the Mighty One.

Have sincere love for God, hanker after God alone, then say whether or not you can see Him.

Comment: Sanjaya says that, not Krishna.

Answer (score 1):

God's description, his deeds as well as his very own lessons to humanity (Bhagavad gita) exist in form of books. If one desires to know about him its only as far as few months of reading some books. Of-course such delicate and subtle topic cant be completely understood just by reading books. There are people who already have a thorough understanding in this field, they would gladly help if anyone seeks for the knowledge.

It is not really appropriate to say that god doesn't wants to be seen where there is so much information lying about him. As a matter of fact in out cut through competitive world we hardly get any time to spare for God, that is perhaps the reason why we know so little about him. Its us not willing to go to great lengths to know about god, rather than him not wanting us to know about him.

This is the basis of kali yuga actually, humans grow insensitive towards subtler spiritual knowledge and try to seek mundane material knowledge and pleasures. In the past yugas there were lot of gurus who would teach about god and philosophy, singers sang songs of god, children were told stories of god. While now thats not the case, we prefer a lot of other things over the knowledge of god. That is the reason out modern society is so ignorant about god.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.

Comment: Thank you.. Sure i would cite sources from now on.This answer is rather general concussion i formed from the knowledge i have, so couldnt cite particular sources.

Answer (score 1):

> [Bhagavad Gita 7.25](https://asitis.com/7/25.html)
>
> नाहं प्रकाशः सर्वस्य योगमायासमावृतः ।
>
> मूढोऽयं नाभिजानाति लोको मामजमव्ययम् ॥

**Meaning**:

> **I am never manifest to the foolish and unintelligent**. For them I am
> covered by My internal potency, and therefore they do not know that I
> am unborn and infallible.

**Explaination:**

According to Shankara, this verse states about the reason why qualified Brahman cannot be realised. Being covered by Yoga-Maya, Lord only manifests some devotees only. As a result they don't know that Lord is unborn and infallible.

---

Prabhupada says when krishna lived, only a few people understood that Krishna is supreme and others had no idea that Krishna is supreme. He was not revealed to the non-devotees and the common man.

---

Comment: By this explanation does it mean that god is within us right now and only few can see him/her as supreme, the rest non believers are unable to spot.

Answer (score 0):

That is because God is formless and cosmic consciousness
There is just 1 God represented by sound OM and he is **OMnipresent, OMnipotent and OMniscient. Singular, Formless,All pervading and Father of all**

> [Ekam Brahman, Dvitya Nasti](https://www.speakingtree.in/blog/god-is-one-and-only-part-1-hinduism) 
>   Only one Brahman/Father/Cosmic consciousness 
>   and nothing else.[Brahm Sutras]
>
> 1. "*Ekam evadvitiyam*"
>      "He is One only without a second."
>      [Chandogya Upanishad 6:2:1]
> 2. "*Na casya kascij janita na cadhipah*."
>      "Of Him there are neither parents nor lord."
>      [Svetasvatara Upanishad 6:9]2
> 3. "**Na tasya pratima asti***"
>      "There is no image of Him."
>      [Svetasvatara Upanishad 4:19]3**
> 4. **Na samdrse tisthati rupam asya, na caksusa pasyati kas canainam*." "His form cant be seen; no one can see Him with the body’s eyes."**
>      [Svetasvatara Upanishad 4:20]4
>
> **6 "shudhama poapvidham**"
>    "He is bodyless and pure." 
>    [Yajurveda 40:8]

Yama's explanation to [Nachiketa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nachiketa) is a succinct explication of Hindu metaphysics, and focuses on the following points from

> 2. The sound *Om!* is the syllabus of the supreme Brahman
> 3. **The Atma(Cosmic Conciousness), whose symbol is Om is the same as the omnipresent Brahman. Smaller than the smallest and larger than the largest, the Soul is formless and all-pervading and cant be seen with human eyes.**

Comment: Who told you that God is always formless?And these english words are related with OM:):)

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee even the greek word "Ohm"  and linked with bio-electricity/electricity, is this same Om, Om was called Ankh in ancient Egypt. Omega/Om means last in Greek and hence represents Shiva-the destroyer.

Comment: Omni word created out of OM sound means everything. PIE languages

Answer (score 0):

Becaues whoever sees God gets liberated and if all get liberated, God's play in form of the world will end which God being a playful One does not want-- thus spake Sri Ramakrishna in His gospel.

Comment: Need  to cite some sources. Probably from Sri Ramakrishna's gospel as mentioned in the answer.